# Can you use a create table query in the data set query section in SSRS 2008

Tags: ssrs-2008

I am using SSRS 2008. My DBA won't allow me to use Stored Procedures. I am creating a data set and have to use the Query section. Can you use a Create Table type of query here?
IF so how?

Answer (score 0):

There is a possibility to create a query from the temporary tables, but for that part of creating the table, there is no solution.

in the window for the query:

```
SELECT TOP 3 INTO #TempTable FROM someTable WHERE someTable.Id = 11091979
```